# How to use one .xib cell in two collectionview in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, xib, viewcontroller

**I have designed one xib cell for collectionview, but i need same design in two collectionviews in one viewcontroller, how to use?**

common one xib class:

```
import UIKit

class MainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var imgProduct: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbRealPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDiscountedPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblLine: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblOff: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgOff: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
}
```

for one collectionview i will write code like this but i need to use same xib cell in `collectionViewTwo`, how

i havent worked on this concept before.. so i dont know is it possible or not

if possible how? i want to use same design in two collectionviews

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MainCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell")
 
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("yourItemView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! yourItemView
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to register your nib on both collection views.